# Bypass ASP MVC bundle requests from MVC module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle, httpmodule

I have HttpModule in place for URL encryption; I noticed this module is also intercepting MVC bundle requests; even if I am using following settings:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
<add ..preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Is there any way to bypass the interception of MVC bundle requests from HttpModule?

Answer (score 1):

so for ignoring certain route in httpmodule you can use Application_BeginRequest or Application_EndRequest , do as below in example which ignores aspx pages or check for the path you want to ignore

Example :

```
 private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source,  EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension =  VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

But if your functionality is related to some modules of application I suggest make use of `Filters`(MVC sepcific and for modules) rather than `HttpModules`(Specific to full application).

Comment: There won't be any extension for regular MVC actions and I won't be able to distinguish between bundle requests and MVC action request.

Comment: @user4903642 - atleast you can check for the route ...because i guess route are diffrent in mvc for getting data